# table rows click event verses links

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have around 3000 row's in a table. which display some data of a collection. for example a user's collection. and i have first name, last name, father's name in the rows.

```
user1First  user1Last  user1Father 
user2First  user2Last  user2Father 
user3First  user3Last  user3Father
```

I need an action which leads to viewing complete details of the user. i have three options -

1. Bind click event to individual rows.

   1. using jquery or
   2. onclick attribute
2. Bind one click event to whole table and use event bubbling
3. Add a link column to the rows

**Which one of the above three is most and least expensive from performance point of view. is there any other way to achieve this and is performance friendly.?**

Performance Criteria -

1. Speed is most important.

   1. No UI blocking while adding the row's to the table. - I add them async as they arrive from the server using jquery append
   2. Unbinding time is also important as i clean up all my events when i remove the views.
2. Memory is secondary but not to be ignored as i run the app on mobile too.

Additional Note : 
I am using backbone.js. for event binding. every row is a backbone view itself [which can be removed if i use links]
Its a marionette.collection view

Comment: HMMM, lets see. Loop through 3000 rows to add a click event to each one OR add one click event? I wonder which will be slower.

Comment: i wont be looping through them all. when i create the row i can add a click event at that time. i add the row's dynamically.

Comment: So it still takes time to add the event when you create the row one at a time. Takes no time to add the event if you do not have to add the event. ;) Argument above still applies, you are still looping, just not with a for loop.

Comment: but if i am using event bubbling. it will be slow when i am processing the event triggered on the whole table.

Comment: Did you actually run a test and prove it is slow? Do not assume it, test it! Sounds like "premature optimization"

Comment: i havnt done tests. but it does blocks the UI if a row is clicked or when i try to cleanup the events.

Comment: Well there is no clean up of events if there is one click event. And there is milliseconds of difference between getting the srcElement and getting the reference from the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that events bubble whether you have attached event handlers higher up the DOM tree or not.

The primary performance criticisms of delegated events are for event bindings that *don't always fire*.  For example, if you attached a delegated event to the table and *some* of your rows fit the selector and some others didn't, then you would pay a performance penalty for checking the CSS selector each time an event bubbled through the table whether or not the row matched the stated criteria.

If you attach a delegated handler then whether and how much of a performance hit you incur depends on the selector.  For example, if your selector is '`td`' then the check is a one step process: `e.target.tagName === 'TD'`.  If, however, your selector is '`tr`' then the check involves dereferencing the parent of e.target to discover that yes, that element *is* a '`tr`' and the event will fire.

For the most part delegated events that are bound close to the event source and that usually match the selector when an event does occur don't incur *much* of a performance penalty.  Usually code simplicity and memory usage will trump in these circumstances and you *should* use delegation.

Comment: i dont have any selection criteria. every row has an id and i just need that id on click.

Comment: Then I would recommend `$('#tableId').on('click', 'tr', function() {})`.  Based on your description the "performance hit" of delegation will be very very minimal and more favorable than the memory footprint and time overhead of allocating 3000 instances of your click handler, even if you only create one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that attaching the click event to table and using event bubbling is the best  option. This is both efficient in speed as well as in memory.

Adding links to column will be same as your first option if you are firing an ajax request on click of the link.

Comment: I am not firing any ajax request. I already have the data by the time the row is added. And the question is not about what will happen after the click. but which method itself is most and least expensive.

Comment: in any case option 2 is better, since browser will not have to listen for 3000 events. If you attach 3000 events i fear it can make page unresponsive on a mobile device.

Comment: those 3000 events does make cleanup a problem.